# how to cancel a localNotification taken from an array of strings after being converted to NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification, swift2

Let’s say this StringArray has strings of Dates which are already scheduled in localNotification, is there a way to get those strings, convert them to dates and then remove a certain scheduled date

```
var arr = ["2016-08-27 19:29:50 +0000","2016-09-20 17:19:50 +0000","2016-07-27 10:20:30 +0000"]**

func locaNotification(num:Int)

{

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    let notifTime = NSDate(notificationTime[num])
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)

}
```

Comment: Look for `NSDateFormatter` to transform `NSDate` into `NSString` or `NSString` into `NSDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let arrLocalNotif = UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications
for (let localN in arrLocalNotif) {
     let notificationFireDate = localN.fireDate;
    //convert string array value to date object and Compair this bothdate
    if(compair true) {
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: could you write it please with Swift ?

Comment: just wrote it in Swift and it worked =) thanks a lot

Comment: though i have one last issue !

when i compare both dates in the if statement  i get in the output : 

2016-05-23 13:55:00 +0000
2016-05-23 13:53:38 +0000

which means the condition will never be true because there is always difference in seconds ! do you know any method to ignore comparing seconds ?